# Mapping Odd/Even to nested lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

So I'm trying to manipulate a list with a loop. Changing my list into a string of each integer by changing them to even or odd.

```
Input_List = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

What I would like to have outputted is

```
Input_List = [['odd','even','odd'],['even','odd','even'],['odd','even','odd']]
```

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
for element in Input_List:
    for item in element:
        if item %2==0:
        Input_List[element][x]="Even"
    else:
        Input_List[element][x]="Odd"
        x+=1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were quite near, the smallest change needed to your program is

```
Input_List=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
for i,element in enumerate(Input_List):
    for j,item in enumerate(element):
        if item %2==0:
            Input_List[i][j]="Even"
        else:
            Input_List[i][j]="Odd"
print Input_List
```

Here, I'm using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead, this is because you can refer to elements in a list by using their indices.

You can do it easily by using a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and a list comprehension

```
>>> l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [list(map(lambda x: 'Odd' if x%2 != 0 else 'Even',i)) for i in l]
[['Odd', 'Even', 'Odd'], ['Even', 'Odd', 'Even'], ['Odd', 'Even', 'Odd']]
```

*Small Note* - Your list is missing commas, `[[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]]` must be `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

Another way is to use the logical and operator (`&`) in a nested list comp, like Padraic mentions in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246764/manipulating-lists-python-3-x/30246793?noredirect=1#comment48596098_30246793)

```
>>> [['odd' if i & 1 else 'even' for i in sub] for sub in l]
[['odd', 'even', 'odd'], ['even', 'odd', 'even'], ['odd', 'even', 'odd']]
```

Comment: In Python 3, you need to explicitly pass the return value of `map` to `list`, or you'll wind up with a list of `map` objects.

Comment: or `[['odd' if i & 1 else 'even' for i in sub] for sub in Input_List]]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Obfuscatiooooooon :) I love it when ya use logical operators!

Comment: Oh come on, this is ridiculous. You got pretty much every solution except the obvious one. Add `['Even','Odd'][n%2]` already :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yep. Your answer is great (and reason why it got my +1) ... It is even more obfuscated!

Comment: Hmm, do you really think it's obfuscated? Maybe I've done that kind of thing too often, to me it's the most natural way.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yeah, I came to know that long back when I read your about me

Answer (score 8):

You can use a nested list comprehension :

```
>>> [['Even' if j%2==0 else 'Odd' for j in i] for i in Input_List]
[['Odd', 'Even', 'Odd'], ['Even', 'Odd', 'Even'], ['Odd', 'Even', 'Odd']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't know why nobody did the o̶b̶v̶i̶o̶u̶s̶:

```
[[['Even','Odd'][n%2] for n in i] for i in Input_List]
```

Edit: I have been informed that I misspelled "obfuscated" (though I disagree :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
input_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print [['odd' if i%2 else 'even' for i in sublist]
       for sublist in input_list]
```